# How to prevent traffic from China?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have set up a test machine (g1 small) in us-west-1c. It has just a node.js web site. There are no known users other than myself doing testing. I can understand that anyone now can hit the web site.

My monthly bill shows non-insignificant traffic **Compute Engine Network Internet Egress from Americas to China**. As I am still conducting testing, I need not open the web server to China. Is there a way to cut off traffic requests from China, however China is defined? Am I right to assume egress to China is a result of requests coming from China?

Comment: could you trace the ips of that traffic??

Comment: Rather I suggest to just WHITELIST your machine(s) from which you can tesy

Comment: Here is what appears to be a related question.  https://serverfault.com/questions/695063/stop-china-from-connecting-to-my-google-compute-engine-server

Comment: Use ipset for geoip blocking

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be getting crawled by bots...search engine or otherwise. [This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27627630/what-does-compute-engine-network-internet-egress-mean-to-google-cloud) may have some ideas about locking things down on the application layer. And it would be good for the rest of the accidental traffic, too.

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting crawled by bots of search engines. Add followings to your `/robots.txt`.

```
User-agent: Baiduspider
Disallow: /
User-agent: Sogou web spider
Disallow: /
User-agent: 360Spider
Disallow: /
User-agent: ChinasoSpider
Disallow: /
User-agent: Sosospider
Disallow: /
```

There are so many search engines in China. You can enter https://www.baidu.com/robots.txt to see more UAs of Chinese search engines' spiders.