# Network Internet Standard Egress from Jakarta in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-vpc, google-cloud-billing

Hello I have a question about Compute Engine in Google Cloud Platform, this is my first time building webhosting in google cloud with Compute Engine.

I think its too costly with a bill for **$80/day** with traffic avg **100.000 page view/day**.

so I'm trying to figure out what services cost the most.

So I got to "Network Internet Standard Egress from Jakarta" which is almost **90%** of daily cost.

I referred this documentation: - [What does 'Compute Engine Network Internet Egress' mean to Google Cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27627630/what-does-compute-engine-network-internet-egress-mean-to-google-cloud/27660439#27660439) and it says

> "Network Internet Egress is *the traffic exiting or downloaded from
> Google Cloud Platform*

so I assumed **Network Internet Egress** directly proportional to the number of **website visitors**.

The question is, is it normal ? or I can do something to decrease the cost ?

**this is the VM specification**

1. VM instances Zone asia-southeast2-a (jakarta)
2. Standard Persistent Disk 1000 GB (jakarta)
3. machine type e2-highmem2 (2 vCPUs, 16GB memory)
4. Network Interface default

Answer (score 0):

You can try to estimate the cost of egress traffic first by estimating how much traffic is needed per one visit (on average). If you don't know you may try to experiment and measure this.

Then multiply it by 100 000 and you have the number.

If "one visit" equals 20 MB of traffic then you have 200 GB of traffic per day.

You can find [Internet egress rates here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing#internet_egress) (they're 0.19 USD/GB for Jakarta). So - 200GB * 0.19 gives 38 USD per day. But you mentioned 80 USD so maybe you'r assumptions were different.

Here's some [VM Instances pring](https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing#general-purpose_machine_type_family) and [Disk and Images pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/disks-image-pricing) documentation.

You can fallow some [best practices described for optimising network costs](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/networking/networking-cost-optimization-best-practices) but it's mainly up to you to keep the traffic in check.